# Find words or sentence from a richtextbox and add into a list C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, richtextbox

I have a log file loaded in a RTB, on another form from the main form. I would like to have a 'find' function for the form, such that I can find the keyword I key in a textbox from the whole log file. Then I want to store those keywords in a list if there is multiple results.

I already separated the whole log file by code:

```
 char[] delimiters = new char[] { ' ', '\n', '\t', ',', '.', '[', ']', ':' };
        string[] searching = searchText.Split(delimiters);
        List<string> splitResult = new List<string>();
        List<string> searchResult = new List<string>();

        foreach (string s in searching)
        {
            splitResult.Add(s);
        }
```

What should i do next? Any idea? or is there a way to actually launch text editor like notepad when i try to open the file?

I tried

```
foreach (string s in splitResult)
        {
            if (splitResult.Contains(txtbox1.Text))
            {
                searchResult.Add(s);
            }
        }
```

but no results

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?:

```
string stringToSearch = "whatever";

if (Array.IndexOf(searching, stringToSearch.ToLower()) > -1)
{
    //String found
}
```

Note that I included "ToLower()" because I understand that you want a match without caring about caps.

This is a much quicker option to find matches than what you are using. Nonetheless, bear in mind that what you intend to do is impossible: you are dividing the content in a textbox into its constituent elements and then you look for this whole content in each of them. For example: the textbox has 1*safda*32, you divide it into "1", "safda" and "32" and then you intend to locate "1*safda*32" in "1", in "safda", etc.

I see two options:

1. Creating a list with suggestions for the user. That is, the contents
   in the array `searching` or in the list `splitResult` (not sure why you are
   creating this list, as far as it is a repetition).
2. Setting a new textbox for the user to type a term to search. You can use my code to run this functionality.